# In C#, what is the best way to Parse out and sort by time string?

Tags: c#, vsto

I am reading and loading in files into Excel using C# VSTO and the filenames are something like this:

```
C:\myfiles\1000AM.csv
C:\myfiles\1100AM.csv
C:\myfiles\1200PM.csv
C:\myfiles\100PM.csv
C:\myfiles\200PM.csv
```

And then i am putting these in a list and need to sort these by "time".

How can i convert the string in the format above into a time object that i can use to sort on?

Comment: Personally I'd probably extract the time with string manipulation or regex and then parse it to a `TimeSpan` object and use that for the basis of the sorting.

Comment: DateTime. From practice we figured out that Dates without time and vice versa do not work. But if you do not have one or the other in the input, we can just asume some default - wich will be the same for all.

Comment: @John - my question is whaat is the best way to do that conversion?

Comment: I'm not really awake enough to write a good answer at the moment, but you can extract the time value with the following regular expression: `(?<=\\)(\d{3,4}(?:AM|PM))(?=\.csv)`. This will leave something like 1000AM in `match.Groups[1].Value`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need extract the time parts somehow and then compare them to each other.

You could for example do this using a `Comparison<string>`. Here is an example that uses the [`Span<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.span-1?view=netcore-3.1) type to do this without allocating any additional garbage:

```
List<string> list = new List<string>() { ... }

list.Sort((a, b) => 
{
    //compare AM/PM
    int compareAmAndPm = a.AsSpan().Slice(a.Length - 6, 2)
        .CompareTo(b.AsSpan().Slice(b.Length - 6, 2), StringComparison.Ordinal);
    if (compareAmAndPm != 0)
        return compareAmAndPm;

    //compare the times as integers
    int index = a.LastIndexOf('\\');
    var firstTime = int.Parse(a.AsSpan().Slice(index + 1, a.Length - index - 7));

    index = b.LastIndexOf('\\');
    var secondTime = int.Parse(b.AsSpan().Slice(index + 1, b.Length - index - 7));


    return firstTime.CompareTo(secondTime);
});
```

It should give you a result of this:

C:\myfiles\1000AM.csv
C:\myfiles\1100AM.csv
C:\myfiles\100PM.csv
C:\myfiles\200PM.csv
C:\myfiles\1200PM.csv

Comment: Why does 12pm come after 2pm? 00:00 = 12am, 12:00 = 12pm. OP's sorted example is correct, this one isn't.

Answer (score 0):

From practice we figured out, that a Time or Date on it's own does not work 99% of the cases. We need both plus the timezone to have any *hope* of processing them meaningfully.

That is why we only have things like `DateTime`, nowadays. Ideally those file names should consist of the full DateTime, in UTC and Invariant culture. If you got the option to change how those are created, use it.

However if you consistently only have one part that is not an issue: `DateTime` simply used default values for the other two. And as those two will be consistent, they will work. The only issue will be a finding a culture setting that eats that AM/PM format.